# DOMDocument loadHTMLFile() gets reformatted

Tags: php, dom

I have the following script:

```
$incldoc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$incldoc->loadHTMLFile($filename, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

echo $incldoc->saveHTML();
```

Which loads this file:

```
<div monkey="123"></div>
<div>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
</div>
<monkey>test</monkey>
```

When It gets output it looks like this:

```
<div monkey="123">
    <div>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </div>
    <monkey>test</monkey>
</div>
```

Is there anyway for me to load the file without it getting formatted?

Comment: No. The file is parsed into an object notation. The object is saved back to file. The original formatting is gone as soon as the document is read. You case is strange though, because it changes actual structure. Are you sure that is the exact output for that exact input, or did you make an error while simplifying the example?

Comment: I copied and pasted the output, no simplifying was, as this is the exact output (aside from tabbing)

Comment: just tested your exact code, it doesn't change the structure by me (it simply can't, actually...). Sure you initialized ` $filename` with the correct filename? Or maybe you edited your html file and forgot to upload the edited version, or anything of that kind?

Comment: I get the same result, it expands the div around the entire bit of code. This is not a case of reformatting, it's a case of changing the structure of the code. I suspect it's because of the invalid attributes and elements.

Comment: I was able to fix it by doing this: `$html = '<view>' . file_get_contents($filename). '</view>'; $incldoc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);` But I don't really like that method so if there is a better way I am all ears.

Comment: Is this HTML or XML? If it's not HTML, don't use an HTML parser.

Comment: It's final output will be HTML...

Comment: But the initial input isn't. HTML parsers have to account for all the weirdness that HTML is heir to, and the result is not always pretty – as you are seeing. If you're converting XML to HTML, you may want to look at XSLT

Answer (score 0):

It's a little long, but how about:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root/>');

$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML(file_get_contents($filename));
$doc->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);

$html = implode(
    array_map(
        function($node) use ($doc) {
            return $doc->saveHTML($node);
        },
        iterator_to_array($doc->documentElement->childNodes)
    )
);

echo $html;
```